# Is there a better way of overriding devise controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have to populate a field in my db when a new user signs-up.But this field is not to be filled by the user, instead will be populated by the application in the db. Here is what i tried:

1. Added the extra field(investorId) in the migration file.
2. Overridden the devise controller:

   def create
   super
   if @user.save
   @user.investorId = @user.id + X---> some number
   @user.save
   end
   end

Though it is working fine, but I want to know if there are better ways of doing it since I am doing it for the first time.

Thanks,
Sachin

Comment: Is the investor ID a foreign key relationship to another table or just some custom generated identifier?

Comment: investorId is some custom generated identifier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to generate a value before you create a record, you can use the `before_create` or `after_create` callbacks on the model.

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :generate_investor_id

  private

  def generate_investor_id
    reload
    investor_id = "#{self.id}something"
    update_attribute(:investor_id, investor_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: but how he will get @user.id in before_create method ? Better to write in after_create callback

Comment: One way would be to use after_create and update_attribute inside the callback.

Comment: Changed it to after callback

Comment: Thanks SacWebDeveloper...it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Don't override your devise controller, there is no benefit of doing this. Simply put the below logic in your `after_create` callback -

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_create :create_investor_id

  private

    def create_investor_id
      self.update_column(:investor_id, id+some_number)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks LHH, your solution worked like a charm. Any specific drawback of overriding the devise controller?